# Browser Bookmarklet To Pull & Store Selected Text From Active Window

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

Firstly, I should make it clear that I am not a programmer (merely working out the details of an upcoming project). So please go easy on me if some questions sound silly.

Basically, I have a requirement to create a browser bookmarklet. This can be dragged on to the user's status bar. So this is how it should work : when I am on any particular webpage, I can select some chunk of content from the page and click on the bookmarklet. On doing this, the bookmarklet should save all the selected data in my database.

Now, what I would like to know is if this is possible if I also want to store all formatting, hyperlinks,etc from the selected text. For instance, the portion of webpage I select on a browser window may include some images, links, bold text and three paragraphs. Is it possible for me to capture all of these by a simple click of a bookmarklet?

Thanks a lot for the help.

PS : I tried searching for this information on this website, but no answers seem to delve with this specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get some of the way by extracting the selected HTML. To get CSS formatting as well, you'd need some fairly heavy processing, which is beyond the scope of my answer. You'll also need to send the selected HTML to the server, for which you'll need to use Ajax.

The Ajax part is fairly simple. There are tons of tutorials around on how to post a value to the server using Ajax. However, you need to be aware that it will only work on a page from the same domain as the server you're posting to, so this may negate the point of doing this as a bookmarklet, since it can't just be used anywhere on the web.

Here's a function that gets the current selected HTML in all major browsers:

```
function getSelectionHtml() {
    var html = "";
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var container = document.createElement("div");
            for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
            }
            html = container.innerHTML;
        }
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
        if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
            html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
        }
    }
    return html;
}

alert(getSelectionHtml());
```